# Negative norm states

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, gauge-theory, brst

If we have negative norm states such that $[a,a^\dagger]=-1$ how do we treat the normalization of two particle states ?

Suppose: $|aa\rangle = N a^\dagger a^\dagger |0\rangle$, after some work we find that:

$$\langle aa | aa \rangle = N^2 \langle 0| a a a^\dagger a^\dagger|0\rangle = +2N^2$$

What does this mean for the normalization constant N? Is it chosen $N=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}$ such that the norm of that timelike state is negative as would be $\langle a|a\rangle$ or do we set $N=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$ such that we have a timelike state with positive norm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation should read
$$
\langle aa | aa \rangle = +2|N|^2
$$
instead of just $N^2$.

As usual, the phase of $N$ is irrelevant (unphysical, unmeasurable, etc.), so you can choose whatever sign you want.

Comment: Ok, so the norm of a two particle state is positive ?

Comment: @gertian yes, you cannot modify the sign of the norm of a state by multiplying it with a scalar; you can only change its magnitude,

Comment: Does this mean that states with two temporal and two longitudinal photons are unphysical since I get.
$\langle a_t a_t|a_t^\dagger a_t| a_ta_t\rangle = -2$ and $\langle a_l a_l|a_l^\dagger a_l| a_la_l\rangle = 2$ such that the gupta Bleuler condition is not satisfied for that state.

I always thought that Gupta Bleuler demanded an equal amount of temporal and longitudinal photons but it appears to mean an equal and odd amount ?
Ps: thanks for helping me out. Its a bit stupid but this got me really confused...

Comment: @gertian the GB condition demands an equal number of temporal and longitudinal photons, but it does **not** demand this number to be odd. It can be even as well.

Comment: Oh I see my mistake. Damn this hasn't been my brightest moment...
Thanks for clearing everything out for me !

Comment: no worries! :-)